# Starting weblogic 12.2.1.2.0 causing issue

Tags: weblogic

I am try to start weblogic 12.2.1.2.0 using startWebLogic.sh command

It is showing the error as below :-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: weblogic.i18n.logging.CatalogMessage.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;I[Ljava/lang/Object;Lweblogic/i18n/Localizer;)V
        at weblogic.security.SecurityLogger.logDisallowingCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification(SecurityLogger.java:15099)
        at weblogic.security.utils.SecurityUtils.turnOffCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification(SecurityUtils.java:98)
        at weblogic.Server.embeddedMain(Server.java:78)
        at weblogic.Server.main(Server.java:137)
Stopping Derby server...
Derby server stopped.
```

Thank you! can anyone please help me to shot out this problem.

Regards,
Richard

Answer (score 0):

It seems the oracle_common\modules\com.bea.core.i18n.jar file is corrupted.
Get that jar file from a backup file and try again.